# wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) on destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

`users_controller.rb`:

```
  def check
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user = @user.checks.where(user_id: @user.id)
    @user.destroy

    if @user.destroy
      redirect_to users_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

The above code is throwing `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)` error on `@user.destroy` line. Any idea?

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Why destroy and save the user?
Why check the user that you just found by id to see if it matches the id?

Comment: Hey Ray, you really need to tell us what you're trying to do here so we can help :)

Comment: Ray, please look at my answer and see if that answers your question. If not, let me know what you are trying to do exactly. I will try to update my answer with your follow up questions. Thanks.

Comment: What is `@user.checks.where(user_id: @user.id)`? Does checks (an association) not use user_id as the foreign key anyway, rendering the where method redundant?

Comment: my bad that should be `ckeck_id: @user.id`

Comment: So it should be `@user = @user.checks(check_id: @user_id)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `destroy` on an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object (**Because your `@user` object is essentially an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object when you call: `@user = @user.checks.where(user_id: @user.id)`**) without passing any id to that and that's why you are getting this error:

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1).
```

You have to pass `id` or array of `ids` when you call `destroy` on an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object. [See this for reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-destroy).

So, to destroy a single user, you can do:

```
User.destroy(@user.first.id)
```

Or, to destroy multiple users, you can do:

```
User.destroy(@user.pluck(:id)) # if @user = @user.checks.where(user_id: @user.id) returns multiple users
```

If you want to be able to call: `@user.destroy`, then you have to get a particular user, e.g. `@user.first`. Then, you can call: `@user.first.destroy`, otherwise not. Hope this clears up the things.

Also, as it's not very clear that what you want to delete, if you want to delete checks, then you should use `Check.destroy(...)`.

#### Udpate:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@user = @user.checks.where(user_id: @user.id)
@user.destroy
```

You should rename the second variable to something more meaningful and verbose e.g. `@user_checks` because it's returning the checks for that user, and then your `@user.destroy` will still be valid as it is because then it's a particular user with `id = params[:id]`.

Comment: This is correct. I'm not sure why someone downvoted it. +1

Comment: Two downvotes? This is really surprising! Downvoters, please comment to point out the problem with the answer, rather than downvoting unanimously and running away!

Comment: Because noone nows what OP tries to do but you rush to give generic answer. That's not the SO I know. Maybe OP wants to destroy the user but maybe their checks, or maybe something completely else. You don't know so you should clarify instead of rushing to be first to answer. This behaviour is ruining the value of SO.

Comment: @MichalSzyndel No, you are not right, we have seen a problem, that he is trying to destroy an ActiveRecord::Relation object, and THAT is why he is seeing the error that he told us in the first place. We gave him a valid answer.

Comment: @MichalSzyndel What are you talking about? His answer is fine and this is the correct answer. It is not our job to guess what OP wants. His question was "do you know why I get this error in my code?" and this question has been answered. If he wants to know something else, he should give us more details and be more specific in his question.

Comment: @MichalSzyndel, This is not a generic answer. This is addressing exactly what the problem is. He is calling `destroy` on an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object without passing any id to that and that's why he is getting this error: `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`. Why do you think it's a generci answer? I request the downvoters to review their votes, please!

Comment: @epergo well... looking at action name and the code I would rather guess OP is trying to destroy all checks for the user, then the user. Or maybe without the user, I honestly don't know. It's weird enough in itself, doesn't hurt to ask, unless you only care about the points ;-)

Comment: @Statyx if only thing you care about are points then yes, it doesn't matter what a beginner programmer has a problem with. But clarifying not only helps you to give a better answer but also helps OP to learn, debug, ask questions, etc.

Comment: @MichalSzyndel yes true, but in this case it was a clear problem. Why he is getting that particular error. And, after that if the OP has any follow up question, we can always update answer and answer more of his follow up questions.

Comment: You CAN'T just downvote a correct answer just because it's the first and quick answer!

Comment: @KMRakibulIslam it wasn't correct when I down voted it, sorry. Let's make a deal that I will keep trying to help and teach people about programming and you will just show them how to get rid of their exceptions without understanding underlying problem, ok? And let's go separate ways.

Comment: You still think it's an incorrect answer and deserves a downvote? Then, I have nothing to say, not anymore :-) Thanks @MichalSzyndel
If you think otherwise, you can revoke your downvote.

Comment: @MichalSzyndel why do think that you are the only one to help and teach people here? That's wrong again. I am also here to help people, and solving their problem, and I am also learning along the way. Looks like you assume many things about others without even knowing. I earnestly request you to change this type of mentality.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the code in the original question looks very odd to me, and that speaks to potential misunderstandings of Rails by the OP which could do with being addressed. By addressing and correcting the symptoms you are not necessarily addressing the problems, and that could cause the OP to come back to ask more questions based on the same or similar misunderstandings. This `User.destroy(@user.first.id)` also looks like atypical code. I would prefer an answer that addresses the entire check method and shows how it ought to be written to achieve the required functionality.

Comment: I should add that I did downvote the question, because a person looking here for a solution to this type of problem is going to see some very strange code that will not help their learning experience.

Comment: @DavidAldridge I totally agree with you. I am waiting for OP's feedback. If he explains what he is trying to do exactly, I will update my answer again to address that.

Answer (score 0):

With this line

```
@user = @user.checks.where(user_id: @user.id)
```

You are obtaining an ActiveRecord::Relation object, just check it out doing:

```
@user.checks.where(user_id: @user.id).class
```

And then trying to destroy that object. 
So what you have to do is: obtain an object to destroy, try this way:

```
@user = @user.checks.where(user_id: @user.id).first
```

Then you can destroy it.

Answer (score -1):

I think you may want to change this line

```
@user = @user.checks.where(user_id: @user.id)
```

This is returning an array of checks.  Not sure what you mean here, but assigning to the @user variable is probably not what you wanted.

Comment: I would think that the where method is redundant on that anyway.